# Generate s3 signature with no access to aws cli

Tags: java, amazon-s3, sas

Really hitting a wall with this one so be great to get a bit of guidance. Basically I have a client who uses sas 9.3 and has no s3 connector or aws cli but I need to connect to s3 so the only way I can do it is useing grroovy and the java libraries however I can't get this to work. Everytime I try do this I get a

The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

error message. I was wondering has anyone exp with this or could someone please help me on this as I can't get it to work. Thanks very much in advance.

Code:

```
proc groovy;
add sasjar="commons_codec" ;

submit "&s3secret." "&stringToSign.";
import javax.crypto.Mac
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
def base64hmacsha256(key, message) {
    mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256"))
    sha1_bytes = mac.doFinal(message.getBytes())
    base64 = new Base64()
    return mac.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF8"));
}
exports.base64hmacsha256 = base64hmacsha256(args[0], args[1])
endsubmit;
quit;
```

Comment: I also tried HmacSHA1 and no luck. Thanks in advance

Comment: paste your error message.

Comment: @eatSleepCode this is it:

The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Comment: You have not shown all of your relevant code.  If your string to sign you generate is wrong, then your signature will also necessarily be wrong.